# Streamsets pipeline didn't finish if kafka consumer having 0 messages in topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, streamsets

I have developed a streamsets pipeline which using KAFKA consumer as origin.My pipeline is working fine if Kafka consumer having message in it.But kafka consumer have 0 message in it the my pipeline went into loop and running contineously and didn't finish.

I need to finish my pipeline if kafka consumer having zero messages in his topic.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is streaming application's nature to keep checking for messages. But a similar approach to what you want to achieve has been [answered-here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800532/how-to-transition-a-streamsets-pipeline-to-finished-state-if-the-origin-does-not).

Comment: The solution you mentioned above will work if at least one lag message in kafka topic .